# How i could use the "username" from the User model as id in other model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new in this and I'm trying to use in Django the username as *id* in other model.
I imported the base model for User in Django, but when i'm doing:

```
 author = User().get_username()
```

The field doesn't appear.

Is there any method to use the `"username"` from the User model?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my English.

Comment: How to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks and sorry.

Comment: technically you don't need. by default django foreign key field would use pk of the targeted model, for your case User.id and that's enough. you're able to get the username by: `object.author.username` or 'author__username' or....

Comment: `User` is a model, so lets say you want to access the username of id 1. Then obj = User.objects.get(pk=1)  followed by obj.get_username(). Does this help @HéctorPrieto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ForeignKey` to relate your current model with `User` model to access its methods.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Then you can call `.get_username()` method to retrieve username. Assuming `my_obj` is `MyModel` class object, calling `my_obj.author.get_username()` will do the job.